# Get Row count from results of a select statement in powershell

Tags: powershell, in-memory-database

I am using the following code to create a small in memory database that reads its source from a CSV file. When I query with a select statement the number of rows always returns zero even though I KNOW that the record is in the data.

```
$inMemDB = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
[void]$inMemDB.Columns.Add("sEmailAddress")
[void]$inMemDB.Columns.Add("sSamAccountName")
[void]$inMemDB.Columns.Add("nPhoneNumber")
[void]$inMemDB.Columns.Add("sFirstName")
[void]$inMemDB.Columns.Add("sLastName")
[void]$inMemDB.Columns.Add("sDisplayName")
[void]$inMemDB.Columns.Add("sDepartment")

$recordCount = 0
Import-Csv $cachedEmpCSV |       
        ForEach-Object {
            [void]$inMemDB.Rows.Add($_.'sEmailAddress',$_.'sSamAccountName',$_.'nPhoneNumber',$_.'sFirstName',$_.'sLastName',$_.'sDisplayName',$_.'sDepartment' )
        }

Write-Host $inMemDB.Rows.Count

$oRs = ($inMemDB.Select("sEmailAddress = 'test@test.com'"))
Write-Host $oRs.Rows.Count
        
If ($oRS.Rows.Count -eq 1) {
    Write-Host $oRs.sSamAccountName
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However neither method worked

Comment: Your $oRs dataset is easily querable by using $oRs.Count instead of $oRs.Rows.Count.

Answer (score 0):

[`DataTable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-7.0#system-data-datatable-select) outputs `DataRow[]` and [`DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-7.0) instances don't have a `.Rows` property. `$oRs.Rows` is null in your example, so `$oRs.Rows.Count` is also null and should be changed to simply `$oRs.Count`.

```
$inMemDB = [System.Data.Datatable]::new()
$inMemDB.Columns.AddRange(@('sSamAccountName', 'sEmailAddress'))
$null = $inMemDB.Rows.Add('foo', 'bar')
$result = $inMemDB.Select("sEmailAddress = 'bar'")
$result.Count # => 1
```